# Eventbrite Customer Calender for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, eventbrite

I am looking for a custom calender widget to integrate in asp.net site. there is one for wordpress but i can not find it for asp.net..i need a widget like this

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a product manager for the Eventbrite API, so hopefully I can help you out.

The Calendar that you're showing is an integration that was built for the WordPress.com platform, and isn't available elsewhere.

There is an open source library for .NET which you might find helpful: https://github.com/penguinboy/Eventbrite.NET

Alternatively, Eventbrite does have a calendar widget that can be plugged into any website: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#calendar

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes that calendar is a good widget but  can i use my css styling with that calendar widget.? if i can that would be awsome.